# Tooltip image gets stuck after hovering on an element in Chrome

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, tooltip

We have a tooltip which appears when you mouse over a small (?) image. However, in Chrome, when you *un-hover* (mouse out), a part of the image on our tooltip somehow still displays, like a ghost image of some sort.

This is the jsFiddle Test Case:

http://jsfiddle.net/UYxBt/

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) test case?

Comment: I now added a test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use inline element `'.tooltip span'`. Use `'div'` or add `'display:block'` to this span on your `css` file.

http://jsfiddle.net/fliptheweb/UYxBt/1/

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can you let me know why adding display: block solves the problem?

Comment: I found this article http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/ and hope this helps you understand